# How can I solve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, dompdf

My composer json is like this :

https://pastebin.com/6aedCGt4

I do : `composer update`

There exist error like this :

> $ composer update
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - laravelcollective/html dev-master requires illuminate/http 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.5.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> - laravelcollective/html dev-master requires illuminate/http 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.5.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> - Installation request for laravelcollective/html dev-master -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[dev-master].
> ```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The message it's self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability, try setting minimum-stability to "dev", and run composer update again.

Comment: Can you delete your answer? Because I want to delete my question. My question many downvote

Comment: I'm not deleting my answer. Maybe more beginners will find it and vote it up.  It's a legitimate question for new composer users and the error messages from composer are not very helpful or self-explanatory at all if you haven't dealt with them before.

Comment: I agree with you in this part "_error messages from composer are not very helpful or self-explanatory at all_" (_maybe you should open an issue on github about this and wait for some reply ;-)_), but only if you don't know what you are doing, if you never read the docs of the tools you are using, and so on... There are litterally tons of questions like this and googling a bit it's pretty simple to find the right answer.